# Easy software installation on Linux(Ubuntu/ Linux mint)

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

When a software is installed, it has to be done with the terminal and coding. There are some steps to do which can be difficult for a new user(comes from windows OS). In Windows OS, we can set paths for installation directory, uninstall easily and installation GUI application comes with the software which is very easy to do with using mouse only.
I am new to Linux and love to use it.
Is there any methodologies or softwares which can be very user friendly for application installation with GUI support ? or only the terminal should be used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple. Here are some options:

- Ubuntu Software Center -- This one comes with Ubuntu. It has categories, install buttons, and other options, but isn't very extensible. It has most of the software in the repos in categories, but it can be buggy. Comes by default from 12.04.
- Muon Software Center -- The default software center in Ubuntu-based KDE distros. This one is less buggy, and has most of the same features as Ubuntu Software Center. I would recommend it.

For slightly more involved package management with more options, there are two I can think of:

- Synaptic Packadge Manager -- For all `apt-get` using distros. This one has a lot of options, and can get a lot done for you. It comes installed by default uptil on Ubuntu11.10.
- Muon Package Manager -- Again, the same, but the counterpart to the Muon Software Center. The only difference between this and Synaptic is that this one is Qt, and the other GTK.

Also, for `.deb` files you download:

- GDebi -- A graphical package installer for packages that you download from websites. Good for people who don't want to go through the `sudo dpkg -i ...` thing.